# MySql no output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Okay, i have this code

```
<?php
$email = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['dato'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$username = "mcnsaoia_onsafe";
$password = "XXX";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("mcnsaoia_onsafe",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= '$email'") or die(mysql_error()); 

//fetch tha data from the database 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

but when i run it, it just says Connected to MySQL and it DON'T output anything??
 i have no idea why it does that?!

Comment: it is `mysql_fetch_array` not `mysqli_fetch_array`, BTW, use mysqli_* or PDO instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: if don't work the comment above, please try use your sql this way: 

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=

Comment: user mysqli_* instead of mysql extension, mysql extension is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether rows are returned by your query using `mysql_num_rows()` function.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>1)
{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
}
else
{
echo "No rows found";
}
```

Note : Use mysqli_* functions . mysql_* functions have been deprecated.

Comment: Okay.. is says No rows found, but I don't understand that? There is something at SELECT * FROM users ?!

Comment: are you sure you are comparing correct column .. WHERE id= '$email' ?

Comment: It works if I remove the where condition... but i NEED the where condition.. so i think it has something to do with the php variable? maybe

Comment: yes... print the variable and see if it value exist in table

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' ") or die(mysql_error()); work.. :-) thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

change it with  `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```